# Error C2057: expected constant expression

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, vector

```
if(stat("seek.pc.db", &files) ==0 )
     sizes=files.st_size;

sizes=sizes/sizeof(int);
int s[sizes];
```

I am compiling this in Visual Studio 2008 and I am getting the following error: 
error C2057: expected constant expression
error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0.

I tried using vector  s[sizes] but of no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to notify that it is a compiler-dependent problem, try it with gcc (C99), your code will be compiled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sizes of array variables in C must be known at compile time. If you know it only at run time you will have to `malloc` some memory yourself instead.

Comment: C99 does have variable-length arrays (VLAs), but Microsoft's compiler doesn't support them.  (The `cannot allocate an array of constant size 0` error may be just the compiler being confused.)

Comment: I tried to allocate memory by int *s=new int[sizes];. Its giving me System.AccessViolationException error. Is it because of this?

Comment: @Richa, that sounds more like something .net than C. And `new int[size]` is not C syntax, it's C++.

Comment: Sorry it was C++ only and I got it fixed. I had stored the files in wrong location. Thanks!

Comment: This is a compiler-dependent answer. GCC compiles the statement : "unsigned char message[getLen(cipher)];" But the same code won't compile with MS VS.

Check this out;
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Answer (score 6):

Size of an array must be a compile time constant. However, C99 supports variable length arrays. So instead for your code to work on your environment, if the size of the array is known at run-time then -

```
int *s = malloc(sizes);
// ....
free s;
```

Regarding the error message:

```
int a[5];
   // ^ 5 is a constant expression

int b = 10;
int aa[b];
    // ^   b is a variable. So, it's value can differ at some other point.

const int size = 5;
int aaa[size];  // size is constant.
```

Comment: Can I initialize size to be a variable in `const int size = 5;`?

Comment: @Richa - You must initialize a constant variable. You cannot perform any kind of assignment to it. http://ideone.com/D4L5r

Comment: I tried to allocate memory by `int *s=new int[sizes];`. Its giving me System.AccessViolationException error. Is it because of this?

Comment: @Richa - Please post the code of what you are doing. There is nothing wrong with the `new`. Probably you are accessing an index beyond 0 to sizes - 1.

Comment: I got it fixed. I had stored the files in wrong location. Thanks!