# Cython: Initialize list with length const input raise error on Windows

Tags: python, cython

I want to initialize an int list in a cdef function. This code works well on macOS, but it raises an error on [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11).

Should I upgrade some C interpreter on Windows?
BTW, which deprecated NumPy API do I use?

```
#cython: language_level=3

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef void base_func(const int num) noexcept nogil:
    cdef:
        int[num] out
        int i
    for i in range(num):
        out[i] = 0
```

#### Error Message

```
E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
group.c(3808): error C2057: expected constant expression
group.c(3808): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
group.c(3808): error C2133: '__pyx_v_out': unknown size
error: command 'E:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

# group.c file -- line 3807-3808
static void __pyx_f_5group_base_func(int const __pyx_v_num) {
  int __pyx_v_out[__pyx_v_num]; -- 3808
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303740/error-c2057-expected-constant-expression and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789055/cython-numpy-warning-about-npy-no-deprecated-api-when-using-memoryview